# Word will not be added to dictionary

Tags: arrays, list, scala

I have this method which reads from a text file and should append each line containing a word to a List, dictionary. The words are read in fine (as verified by `println(word)`), however, nothing is appended to `dictionary`. It remains empty.

```
/**
  * Load words from dictionary file.
*/
private def loadDictionary(): Array[String] = {
    var dictionary: List[String] = List()
    try {
        for(word <- Source.fromFile("words.dic").getLines) {
            dictionary :+ word // As I understand, :+ appends to a list?
            println(word) // Prints a word from file e.g. aardvark.
        }   
    }
    catch { // Catch any I/O and general exceptions
        case ioe: IOException => displayError(ioe) 
        case e: Exception => displayError(e)
    }
    dictionary.toArray
}
```

What have I done wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because immutable list produces **new** collection as a result of :+ operation. And you're throwing that collection away.

```
private def loadDictionary(): Array[String] = {
    var dictionary: List[String] = List()
    try {
        for(word <- Source.fromFile("words.dic").getLines) {
            dictionary = dictionary :+ word 
            println(word)
        }
    }
    catch { // Catch any I/O and general exceptions
        case ioe: IOException => displayError(ioe) 
        case e: Exception => displayError(e)
    }
    dictionary.toArray
}
```

Now talking about code clarity -- why do you loop through the lines so imperatively? Why not something like this:

```
    val dictionary: List[String] = try {
        for(word <- Source.fromFile("words.dic").getLines) yield {
            println(word)
            word
        }
    }
    catch {
        case e: Exception => displayError(e); Nil
    }
    dictionary.toArray
```

or just `Source.fromFile("words.dic").getLines.toArray`?

Comment: Is there a better alternative to the list then, a mutable list where i don't have to copy and then reassign? Cheers. I'll do some research into myself in the meantime.

Comment: @SamSaint-Pettersen not quite, since [**prepending** to immutable list is very cheap operation (not **appending** through)](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) and rest of the list is shared when you add new element.